# How do I run certain tests in a different browser using Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have 2 sets of tests. The first set I want to run in Electron. The second set (using WebGL) I want to run in Chrome. How can I tell Cypress to launch a different browser if it sees a certain string in the file path (ex: design-pro)

Answer (score 0):

Well this isn't ideal, but I found a `--project` option.

Essentially you can create a "subproject" in your repo. ex:

```
my-repo
  - package.json
  - cypress.json
  - cypress
     - integration
       - test1.feature
       - test2.feature
     - support
     - plugins
     - ...
  - webgl-project-cypress
   - cypress.json
   - cypress
     - integration
       - test1.feature
       - test2.feature
     - support
     - plugins
     - ...
```

Then in your package.json have:

```
"scripts": {
   "cypress:run": "node_modules/cypress/bin/cypress run --record --key something",
   "cypress:ci": "yarn run cypress:run --parallel",
   "cypress:run:webgl-project-cypress": "yarn cypress:run --browser chrome --project webgl-project-cypress",
   "cypress:ci:webgl-project-cypress": "yarn run cypress:run:webgl-project-cypress --parallel"
 }
```

`cypress:run` is for the first project and `cypress:run:webgl-project-cypress` is for the WebGL stuff